# Akka Cluster-aware Router never sends message to remote nodes

Tags: java, akka

I have run the StatsSampleMain in Akka Cluster Samples with Java, which splits the text into words, sends them to workers and gets the length of each word. In the example, the cluster-aware router (consistent-hashing-group) is used.

However, all of words are only sent to the same local node. I expect that the words are routed to all workers in cluster based on the hashing algorithm. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: We need some code.

Comment: The code is [here](http://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/bundle/akka-sample-cluster-java). I did not modify any code.

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that they are sent to the same node?